# How to create a field dependency in apex based on master picklist

Tags: configuration, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

I have a requirement to handle mapping of field dependencies of picklist. I have multiple picklists are there in case object, for example:

> **Scenario 1**

1. `Case Category`: Problem
2. `Case Type`:account Related
3. `Case Subtype`:Add Contact

> **Scenario 2**

1. `Case Category`: Howto
2. `Case Type`:account Related
3. `Case Subtype`:Delete Contact(is only needed in mapping)

But In my case i'm geeting like

1. `Case Category`: Howto
2. `Case Type`:account Related
3. `Case Subtype`:Add Contact,Delete Contact

But with standard field dependencies, I cannot map differently for two picklists values. Because in above scenario based on the main picklist the final picklist values also depend.

Please provide me better solution to handle

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue.

`Case Type:account Related` is under both `Case Category: Problem` and `Case Category: Howto` that's why aggregation of `Add Contact,Delete Contact` will be displayed, whenever you will select `account Related`.

Main issue is Salesforce derives field dependency only one level at a time. If that could be 2 levels at a time like you could select both Category and Type when selecting Subtype then this problem will not get occurred.

I would think of following solutions:

1. Create separate recordtypes which will govern the picklist values of Category, Type and subtype.
2. If that is not possible, then change the case type values like this:

   - `Case Category`: Problem
   - `Case Type` :Problem - account Related
   - `Case Subtype` :Add Contact

   And for other scenario

   - `Case Category`: Howto
   - `Case Type` :Howto - account Related
   - `Case Subtype` :Delete Contact

Comment: Ya you are right already i'm working in recordtype only.Is there any way through visualforce and apex

Comment: recordtype is best approach, otherwise custom coding can be done